# Como usar expoente em Pascal?

Tags: matemática, pascal

Tenho um problema para resolver, onde na fórmula de PG se usa expoente diferente de dois (ao quadrado), não podendo usar `sqrt()`.

De que forma posso resolver isso em Pascal de uma forma intuitiva?
Sei que não se pode usar `**` também.

Fórmula :  `an = a1 . q(n – 1) // q elevado à n -1`

Comment: Vê se a [**documentação**](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/power.html) pode te ajudar nesse caso. Monte um *script* e qualquer coisa a gente tá aqui pra ajudar. Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

```
an = a1 * power(q, n – 1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/Power.pas).

[Documentação](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/power.html).

Answer (score 1):

x elevado a y é igual a exp(y*ln(x))

Exemplo:

```
Program Exemplo;
var
a, b : Integer;
begin
  a := 5;
  b := 3;
  writeln (exp(b*ln(a)):10:0);
  readln;
end.
```